Snowflake SQL Alchemy on a Lambda Function
Hi building an application that interacts with Snowflake and needs to utilize an SQLAlchemy create_engine to interact with Snowflake. The issue being when I import SQLAlchemy, Snowflake.Connector and Snowflake.sqlalchemy I keep getting a few issues.
When including all three libs I get the following error:
Unable to import module snowflake-sqlalchemy.
When removing Snowflake-Aqlalchemy I get the following error:
Does not recognise snowflake as a dialect for SQLAlchemy.
When I run locally everything works fine.
Does anyone know what versions I should use and what is the best way of getting this to work?

Assuming you're building a deployment package (a .zip of a virtual environment), you'd have to build the package on an Amazon Linux 2 OS machine (or w/in a docker container running AL2). If you look into the logs around the import error and see something about gcc or development headers, this is almost certainly what's wrong.
The easiest way to do this is just spin up a quick docker container running amazonlinux, copy your requirements file into there, build your deployment package like normal, and copy the output to a volume you can access from your dev machine. Then upload the deployment package like normal. I found a medium post that describes a similar process in more detail here- https://medium.com/simform-engineering/creating-lambda-layers-made-easy-with-docker-a-developers-guide-3bcfcf32d7c3
A lot of database connector packages are like this- they rely on non-python libraries being built under the hood to talk to the database. If you think you'll be connecting to snowflake from multiple lambda functions, it would make sense to build a lambda layer in your account and use that instead of a deployment package. Layers are basically reusable sets of dependencies that you can apply to your lambda functions, and you can mix & match layers (so if you need pandas and snowflake for a lambda, you can add your snowflake and pandas layer to that function w/o making a new one just for that function). AWS docs for lambda layers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-layers.html
If you don't want to mess with docker, you can always just spin up (tiny) ec2 instance running amazon linux, paste in your requirements.txt, build the package there, and copy it back down to your local machine over ssh. If you're regularly rebuilding your app, that gets kind of annoying, but it works for now. Eventually, you may find it worthwhile to automate some of the deployment package building, either through automation tools like GitHub Actions, or a bash script in your repo. I'd start with a bash script for deploying your lambda, as most CI/CD tools ultimately run a few bash commands
